# How to combine two rasters into one layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-calculator

I need to combine two raster layers into one. Layer A has soil information for the entire state, but contains gaps. Layer B contains soil information for Layer A's gaps. What's a simple way to combine these two rasters into one "seamless" layer? Both layers have the same four values (1 - 4) and are the same pixel size, type, etc.

I don't want to create a mosaic dataset, I want one actual layer.

Comment: Do you have spatial analyst extension?

Comment: Con(isnull(a), b,a) using raster calculator.

Comment: yes, i have spatial analyst extension!

Answer (score 3):

Use [Raster calculator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm) to solve this issue. It's pretty simple to use.

In this case, [`Con()` evaluator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/conditional-evaluation-with-con.htm) is a good approach. It has this form:

```
Con(in_conditional_raster, true_raster, {false_raster})
```

So, in your case will be something like:

```
Con("Layer A - Band_1" > 0, "Layer A - Band_1", "Layer B - Band_1")
```